# chr field to as.date with Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols

Tags: r

I have dataframe with a field called run_date.  It imports as a Chr field and I'm trying to covert it to a date field as follows:

```
zUXQ_Boxes_Master <- zUXQ_Boxes_Master %>% mutate_at(var(run_date), as.Date)

structure(list(url = "/survey/selfserve/5c3/200818?list=18", 
    segment = "Novice", XUSE_Usefulness_topbox = 0.8, XUSE_Usefulness_middlebox = 0.2, 
    XUSE_Usefulness_bottombox = 0L, XUSE_Ease_topbox = 0.6, XUSE_Ease_middlebox = 0.4, 
    XUSE_Ease_bottombox = 0L, XUSE_Learning_topbox = 0.8, XUSE_Learning_middlebox = 0.2, 
    XUSE_Learning_bottombox = 0L, XUSE_Satisfaction_topbox = 0.8, 
    XUSE_Satisfaction_middlebox = 0.2, XUSE_Satisfaction_bottombox = 0L, 
    XSnow_topbox = 0.8, XSnow_middlebox = 0L, XSnow_bottombox = 0.2, 
    XEffective_topbox = 0.8, XEffective_middlebox = 0.2, XEffective_bottombox = 0L, 
    X_Effective_Functional_topbox = 0.8, X_Effective_Functional_middlebox = 0.2, 
    X_Effective_Functional_bottombox = 0L, X_Effective_Useful_topbox = 0.8, 
    X_Effective_Useful_middlebox = 0.2, X_Effective_Useful_bottombox = 0L, 
    X_Effective_Performant_topbox = 0.4, X_Effective_Performant_middlebox = 0.4, 
    X_Effective_Performant_bottombox = 0.2, XEfficient_topbox = 0.8, 
    XEfficient_middlebox = 0.2, XEfficient_bottombox = 0L, X_Efficient_Efficient_topbox = 0.8, 
    X_Efficient_Efficient_middlebox = 0.2, X_Efficient_Efficient_bottombox = 0L, 
    X_Efficient_Ease_topbox = 0.6, X_Efficient_Ease_middlebox = 0.4, 
    X_Efficient_Ease_bottombox = 0L, X_Efficient_Learn_topbox = 0.8, 
    X_Efficient_Learn_middlebox = 0.2, X_Efficient_Learn_bottombox = 0L, 
    XEmpowered_topbox = 0.4, XEmpowered_middlebox = 0.2, XEmpowered_bottombox = 0.4, 
    X_Empowered_Satisfaction_topbox = 0.4, X_Empowered_Satisfaction_middlebox = 0.2, 
    X_Empowered_Satisfaction_bottombox = 0.4, X_Empowered_Empowered_topbox = 0.8, 
    X_Empowered_Empowered_middlebox = 0.2, X_Empowered_Empowered_bottombox = 0L, 
    X_Empowered_Enjoyable_topbox = 0.4, X_Empowered_Enjoyable_middlebox = 0.4, 
    X_Empowered_Enjoyable_bottombox = 0.2, run_date = "2021-06-25", 
    study_name = "enter your study name here i.e problem.paris.2021", 
    TaskCompletionRate = 0.775, WeightedEffective = 384, WeightedEfficient = 240L, 
    WeightedEmpowered = 40L, WeightedScore = 66.4, ExperienceGrade = "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Whenever I run it, it says, Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols.

Any help fixing this would be appreciated as it works on other df's I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mutate_at` you need `vars`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(run_date), as.Date)
```

Since you want to change a single column you can also do

```
df <- df %>% mutate(run_date =  as.Date(run_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
       mutate(across(all_of(run_date), as.Date))
```